# Flash AS2 float to currency string?

Tags: flash

Is it possible to convert a float to a currency string in Flash AS2?

Cheers,
MiG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a basic implementation here that served my needs:

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14267.html

Apparently there is no native implementation in AS2 which sucks.

Comment: why should there be? when AS2 was released, the Flash Player was about 800KB to download, simply because it didn't contain tons of things that you may need. the ActionScript standard library is basically just an interface to the flash player itself and nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

you should probably go into detail a little further, because the answer to your current question is simply: yes.